# Returning HTTP error codes from BrowserViews in Plone

Tags: plone

Plone views support setting return code on the HTTP response by mutation

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/serving/http_request_and_response.html#return-code

... however does there exist anything Pyramid/Django style where one could return human-readable HTTP error codes from your browser view. Along the lines:

```
class View(BrowserView):

    def __call__(self):
        # Any nice classes to return here?
        return Forbidden("Sauna area is forbidden due to on-going repairement work")
```

Also i am aware of that you can throw zException but that results to "We are sorry, there seems to be..." page on the user. I just want to short plain-text info to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, apart from raising the zException built-in exceptions and calling `self.request.response.setStatus()`, there is no other way for influencing the status code.

Comment: Maybe you missed my edit why exceptions are bad. Please see above.